# R , rattle , recode

Tags: r, record, rattle

***R , rattle***

**here is my data  :**

```
KK<- c('yes','no','yes','yes','dp')
LL<- c('dp','no','yes','yes','no')
II<- c('yes','dp','no','no','no')
JJ<- c('yes','no','yes','yes','dp')
AA<- c('no','dp','yes','yes','yes')
MYDATA <- data.frame(KK,LL,II,JJ,AA);MYDATA
```

**Target：**

recode 「no」 to 「0.0」

recode 「yes」to 「1.0」

recode 「dp」to 「0.5」

**Question:**
how can i recode in r with the package 「rattle」

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We can convert the 'MYDATA' to 'matrix', change the 'character' class to 'factor' by specifying the labels to '0.5, 0, 1' based on the order of levels and assign it back to 'MYDATA'. `[]` will ensure that the structure remains the same.

```
MYDATA[] <- as.numeric(as.character(factor(as.matrix(MYDATA), 
                            labels=c(0.5, 0, 1))))

MYDATA 
#   KK  LL  II  JJ  AA
#1 1.0 0.5 1.0 1.0 0.0
#2 0.0 0.0 0.5 0.0 0.5
#3 1.0 1.0 0.0 1.0 1.0
#4 1.0 1.0 0.0 1.0 1.0
#5 0.5 0.0 0.0 0.5 1.0
```

Answer (score 2):

Assuming that you are looking for a numeric result:

```
(MYDATA == "dp") / 2 + (MYDATA == "yes")
```

giving:

```
      KK  LL  II  JJ  AA
[1,] 1.0 0.5 1.0 1.0 0.0
[2,] 0.0 0.0 0.5 0.0 0.5
[3,] 1.0 1.0 0.0 1.0 1.0
[4,] 1.0 1.0 0.0 1.0 1.0
[5,] 0.5 0.0 0.0 0.5 1.0
```